# Serial port modem

Tags: linux, usb, port, serial

I'm trying to send commands to my serial port, I have a modem on my USB and I can't connect with putty or minicom for send AT commands.

```
dmesg | grep tty  
[265301.769187] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[265766.120545] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[265848.450853] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[266256.553290] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[266296.890902] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[267710.969347] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[267735.962921] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[267772.749423] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[267807.950927] usb 2-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

And when on minicom return it:

```
Serial device: /dev/tty8;
```

Comment: "i have a modem on my USB" - You might want to mention the fact you have a USB to Serial converter.

Comment: It would appear that your device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`, so you would have to reconfigure minicom from its default settings.